# Oracle modify sys refcursor and return the modified cursor in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle18c, plsql-package

Im trying to create a procedure which takes sys refcursor as in out parameter and modifies it based on the logic explained in comments in the below code

```
TYPE t_params IS
  TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32767 CHAR);
  /
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE modify_cursor (
p_cursor IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
p_array_binary   IN t_params,
p_values         IN t_params
)
/*

p_cursor IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
-- contains a single row {empId:123, ename:"king", mgr:"Porter",deptNo:200}
p_array_binary  IN t_params
-- contains one binary value corresponding to each column in above cursor ["1","0","1","1"] 
p_values  IN t_params
-- contains one binary value corresponding to each column in above cursor ["123","king2","new manager","200"]



*/
IS

BEGIN
    /*
        Based on p_array_binary 
           if binary value 0 then take cursor should retain value as it is fro corresponding column
           if binary value 1 then cusrsor should have the correspondoing column value from p_values 


    In short, the out cursor should be      {empId:123, ename:"king", mgr:"new manager", deptNo:200}     

*/

END;
/
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can not change a cursor. You can only create a new one with corresponding data.

Comment: yeah. Maybe i can create a new cursor and reassign it to the out parameter p_cursor. But how to accomplish that?

Comment: Or is there any way to convert the cursor single row result into an array

Comment: Is the single row in the cursor a single JSON value with four attributes, or four columns? Either way, will it always be four - both in the cursor, and four elements in both `t_params` arguments - or can that vary?

Comment: its four columns. It will not always be four. It can vary. The no .of elements in t_params depend on no.of columns in the ref cursor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you knew the ref cursor structure - it was always four columns of the data types shown - then this would be relatively simple:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE modify_cursor (
p_cursor IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
p_array_binary   IN t_params,
p_values         IN t_params
)
IS
  l_empid number;
  l_ename varchar2(30);
  l_mgr varchar2(30);
  l_deptNo number;
BEGIN
  -- get original values into local variables
  fetch p_cursor into l_empId, l_ename, l_mgr, l_deptNo;
  -- re-open cursor using either local variables of p_values depending on p_binary flag
  open p_cursor for
    select
      case when p_array_binary(1) = '1' then to_number(p_values(1)) else l_empId end as empId,
      case when p_array_binary(2) = '1' then p_values(2) else l_ename end as ename,
      case when p_array_binary(3) = '1' then p_values(3) else l_mgr end as mgr,
      case when p_array_binary(4) = '1' then to_number(p_values(4)) else l_deptNo end as deptNo
    from dual;
END;
/
```

Demo using your sample data, via SQL*Plus/SQL Developer/SQLcl bind variables:

```
var rc refcursor;

begin
  open :rc for
    select 123 as empId, 'king' as ename, 'Porter' as mgr, 200 as deptNo
    from dual;

  modify_cursor(:rc, t_params('1', '0', '1', '1'), t_params('123', 'king2', 'new manager', '200'));
end;
/

print rc

     EMPID ENAME                            MGR                                  DEPTNO
---------- -------------------------------- -------------------------------- ----------
       123 king                             new manager                             200
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fc104097de792d6fe7ecc0f05463301f)

Since you don't know the structure in advance, you will have to use dynamic SQL, which is bit more complicated. Here's an outline:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE modify_cursor (
p_cursor IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
p_array_binary   IN t_params,
p_values         IN t_params
)
IS
  l_c integer;
  l_col_cnt integer;
  l_desc_t dbms_sql.desc_tab3;
  l_varchar2 varchar2(32767 char);
  l_values t_params := new t_params();
  l_result integer;
BEGIN
  -- convert ref cursor to dbms_sql cursor
  l_c := dbms_sql.to_cursor_number(rc => p_cursor);
  -- analyse the cursor (columns, data types)
  dbms_sql.describe_columns3(c => l_c, col_cnt => l_col_cnt, desc_t => l_desc_t);
  -- optionally check l_col_cnt matches sise of t_params arguments?
  l_values.extend(l_col_cnt);

  -- define each column for fetch; here you're treating everything as strings,
  -- which will cause issues with some other data types
  for i in 1..l_col_cnt loop
    dbms_sql.define_column(c => l_c, position => i, column => l_varchar2, column_size => 32767);
  end loop;

  -- fetch original values - only one row to worry about so no loop
  l_result := dbms_sql.fetch_rows(c => l_c);

  for i in 1..l_col_cnt loop
    -- depending on p_array_binary, set l_values from either fetched data or p_values
    if p_array_binary(i) = '1' then
      l_values(i) := p_values(i);
    else
      -- this forces everything to varchar2, which is OK (ish) for your sample data;
      -- if you have other data types e.g. dates then you will probably want type-specific
      -- handling so you can control the conversions - which affects this, define_column
      -- and the final cursor to retrieve the values. But you have the same issue with p_values.
      dbms_sql.column_value(c => l_c, position => i, value => l_values(i));
    end if;
  end loop;

  -- finished with original cursor, so close it
  dbms_sql.close_cursor(c => l_c);

  -- re-open ref cursor using l_values data, with another dynamic SQL statement
  l_varchar2 := 'select ';
  for i in 1..l_col_cnt loop
    if i > 1 then
      l_varchar2 := l_varchar2 || ', ';
    end if;
    if l_desc_t(i).col_type = 2 then
      l_varchar2 := l_varchar2 || l_values(i);
    else
      l_varchar2 := l_varchar2 || '''' || l_values(i) || '''';
    end if;
    l_varchar2 := l_varchar2 || ' as "' || l_desc_t(i).col_name || '"';
  end loop;
  l_varchar2 := l_varchar2 || ' from dual';
  open p_cursor for l_varchar2;
END;
/
```

Running exactly the same demo block gives:

```
     EMPID ENAM MGR             DEPTNO
---------- ---- ----------- ----------
       123 king new manager        200
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=087d20b96dcab163cbbcb0d34787a570)

You can add handling for other data types if needed, error handling etc.

Read more about [dbms_sql](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm).

Comment: Now that's awesome.